# Why does my COBOL working storage variable have trailing zeroes?

Tags: cobol

I'm building a COBOL program to calculate the average of up to 15 integers. The execution displays a number that is far bigger than intended with a lot of trailing zeroes. Here is the relevant code:

```
       Data Division.
       Working-Storage Section.
       01 WS-COUNTER          PIC 9(10).
       01 WS-INPUT-TOTAL      PIC 9(10).
       01 WS-NEXT-INPUT       PIC X(8).
       01 WS-CONVERTED-INPUT  PIC 9(8).
       01 WS-AVG              PIC 9(8)V99.

       Procedure Division.
       PROG.
           PERFORM INIT-PARA
           PERFORM ADD-PARA UNTIL WS-COUNTER = 15 OR WS-NEXT-INPUT = 'q'
           PERFORM AVG-PARA
           PERFORM END-PARA.
       INIT-PARA.
           DISPLAY 'This program calculates the average of inputs.'.
           MOVE ZERO TO WS-COUNTER
           MOVE ZERO TO WS-INPUT-TOTAL
           MOVE ZERO TO WS-AVG.
       ADD-PARA.
           DISPLAY 'Enter an integer or type q to quit: '
           ACCEPT WS-NEXT-INPUT
           IF WS-NEXT-INPUT NOT = 'q'
               MOVE WS-NEXT-INPUT TO WS-CONVERTED-INPUT
               ADD WS-CONVERTED-INPUT TO WS-INPUT-TOTAL
               ADD 1 TO WS-COUNTER
           END-IF.
       AVG-PARA.
           IF WS-COUNTER > 1
               DIVIDE WS-INPUT-TOTAL BY WS-COUNTER GIVING WS-AVG
               DISPLAY 'Your average is ' WS-AVG '.' WS-NEXT-INPUT
           END-IF.
```

The reason I put `WS-NEXT-INPUT` as alphanumeric and move it to a numeric `WS-CONVERTED-INPUT` if the `IF` condition is satisfied is because I want it to be able to take "q" to break the `UNTIL` loop, but after the condition is satisfied, I want a numeric variable for the arithmetical statements. Here's what it looks like with the numbers 10 and 15 as inputs:

```
10is program calculates the average of inputs.
Enter an integer or type q to quit:
15
Enter an integer or type q to quit:
q
Your average is 1250000000.
```

The console is a bit buggy so it forces me to input the 10 in that top left corner most of the time. Don't worry about that.

You see my problem in that execution. The result is supposed to be 00000012.50 instead of 1250000000. I tried inserting a few of my other variables into that display statement and they're all basically as they should be except for `WS-INPUT-TOTAL` which with that combination of numbers ends up being 0025000000 instead of 0000000025 as I would have expected. Why are these digits being stored in such a weird and unexpected way?

Comment: You used `V` in the `PICTURE` string, which is correct for computation, but if you want to display it with a decimal point you need to `MOVE` it to a variable with `PICTURE 9(8).99`. You probably also need to sanitize the `PIC X(8)` field before the `MOVE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have that strange output because of undefined behavior - computing with spaces.

The `MOVE` you present has the exact same `USAGE` and same size - it will commonly be taken over "as is", it normally does not convert the trailing spaces by some magic, so `WS-CONVERTED-INPUT` ends up with `10`      . As the standard says for the move:

> De-editing takes place only when the sending operand is a numeric-edited data item and the receiving item is a numeric or a numeric-edited data item.

and if it would be an edited field then it still should raise an exception on the `MOVE`:

> When a numeric-edited data item is the sending operand of a de-editing MOVE statement and the content of that  data  item  is  not  a  possible  result  for  any  editing  operation  in  that  data  item,  the  result  of  the  `MOVE` operation is undefined and an `EC-DATA-INCOMPATIBLE` exception condition is set to exist.

When computing with spaces you commonly would raise a fatal error, but it seems your compile does not have that activated (and because you didn't share your compile command or even your compiler, we can't help with that).

Different COBOL dialects often use (partial only when checks are not activated which would lead to an abort) zero for invalid data, at least for spaces (but they *can* use everything. This will then lead to `WS-CONVERTED-INPUT` "seen as" `10000000` - so your computation will then include those big numbers.

So your program should work if you enter the necessary amount of leading zeroes on input.

General:

- "never trust input data - validate" (and error or convert as necessary)
- at least if something looks suspicious - activate all runtime checks available, re-try.

Solution - Do an explicit conversion:

`MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL(WS-NEXT-INPUT) TO WS-CONVERTED-INPUT`, this will strip surrounding spaces and then convert from left to right until invalid data is found. A good coder would also check up-front using `FUNCTION TEST-NUMVAL`, otherwise you compute with zero if someone enters "TWENTY".

Comment: You could use unstring as well

Comment: With the `NUMVAL` function, the digits are in the right place but it's still not recognizing my floating point.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to COBOL so my questions might seem a bit silly, but I'm noticing in my modules that the `V` is an "implied" position of the decimal point. Does this mean there is no actual decimal point stored in such variables?

Comment: That's a good, but different question - please post a separate one to keep the focus (one question, one answer, that's the stackoverflow principle) and when this answer "works for you" mark it as accepted.